# Consistent access to IOwinContext in Web Forms, MVC, Signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm developing a web application and I want to be able to access currently logged in user through my IUserContext interface. It looks like so:

```
public interface IUserContext
{
    int UserId { get; }
    string UserName { get; }
}
```

This interface can be consumed in my command handlers and query handlers.

Web application uses ASP.NET Identity library version 2.2.1. So, I want to implement the interface using IOwinContext. I have three layers where I need access to owin context:

- ASP.NET Web Forms pages
- ASP.NET MVC 5 actions
- Signalr hub

For web forms pages and MVC actions, I can write custom middleware to populate IUserContext properties ([using code from this doc](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/owinintegration.html)):

```
public interface IOwinContextAccessor
{
    IOwinContext CurrentContext { get; }
}

public class CallContextOwinContextAccessor : IOwinContextAccessor
{
    public static AsyncLocal<IOwinContext> OwinContext = new AsyncLocal<IOwinContext>();
    public IOwinContext CurrentContext => OwinContext.Value;
}

public class OwinUserContext : IUserContext
{
    public int UserId => CallContextOwinContextAccessor.OwinContext.Value.Authentication.User.Identity.GetUserId<int>();
    public string UserName => CallContextOwinContextAccessor.OwinContext.Value.Authentication.User.Identity.Name;
}

    // inside my Startup.cs Configuration method
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        CallContextOwinContextAccessor.OwinContext.Value = context;
        await next();
    });
```

For signalr hub I can create `HubPipelineModule` which will populate `CallContextOwinContextAccessor.OwinContext`:

```
public class OwinContextPipelineModule : HubPipelineModule
{
    protected override bool OnBeforeIncoming(IHubIncomingInvokerContext context)
    {
        var owinContext = context.Hub.Context.Request.GetHttpContext().GetOwinContext();
        CallContextOwinContextAccessor.OwinContext.Value = owinContext;
        return base.OnBeforeIncoming(context);
    }
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is this the correct way of accessing logged in user in ASP.NET
   Identity?
2. Is it safe to reuse `CallContextOwinContextAccessor` inside middleware and hub pipeline module? I've read [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn906268(v=vs.110).aspx) about `AsyncLocal` type and it seems like variable's value persists across methods calls down the call stack. I worry about possible race conditions when one user calls MVC action and at the same time another user calls signalr hub method or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:**

As it turned out, it's much easier to use command object and initialize current user property using appropriate mvc/signalr `User` properties.

E.g.:

```
public class MyCommand
{
    public string Payload { get; set; }
    public IPrincipal CurrentUser { get; set; } // or int UserId, or string UserName
}
```

and then initialize command object:

```
// mvc action
new MyCommand
{
    Payload = "foo"
    CurrentUser = User // User is a Controller.User property
};

// signalr hub
new MyCommand
{
    Payload = "bar"
    CurrentUser = Context.User
};
```

This way, I don't need `IUserContext` at all.
Thanks @Nkosi for figuring that out.

Answer (score 4):

I have another approach which could decouple your implementation concerns from specific OWIN concerns like the `IOwinContext`.

```
public class UserContext : IUserContext {
    private Lazy<IPrincipal> user;

    public UserContext(Func<IPrincipal> valueFactory) {
        this.user = new Lazy<IPrincipal>(valueFactory);
    }

    public int UserId {
        get { return user.Value.Identity.GetUserId<int>(); }
    }

    public string UserName {
        get { return user.Value.Identity.Name; }
    }
}
```

Then from there you can configure everything from the composition root. Based on the linked doc, the assumption is that you are using Simple Injector for DI.

```
void Configure(IAppBuilder app) {
    IPrincipal currentUser = null;
    Func<IPrincipal> activator = () => currentUser;

    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();
    //Only one instance will be created by the container per web request 
    //and the instance will be disposed when the web request ends.
    container.Options.DefaultScopedLifestyle = new WebRequestLifestyle();

    // Register your types, for instance:
    container.Register<IUserContext>(() => new UserContext(activator),
        Lifestyle.Scoped);

    //...Configure respective DI as needed

    //Set MVC DI if needed
    System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver
        .SetResolver(new SimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container));
    //Set Web API DI if needed
    System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver =
        new SimpleInjectorWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    //...use other middleware 

    //...custom middleware to grab user (placed especially after Identity config)
    app.Use(async (context, next) => {
        //get the current user from request pipeline
        currentUser = context.Authentication.User;
        await next();
    });

    app.MapSignalR();
}
```

As demonstrated in the comments above, the main idea being that you configure the IoC container to manage the lifetime and scope of the resolved dependencies for the respective frameworks. The needed information is lazy loaded from the request and passed to the injected context, removing the need to pass the `IOwinContext` around, keeping the user context implementation clean and decoupled.

By configuring the container to use `WebRequestLifestyle` you ensure

> Only one instance will be created by the container per web request and the instance will be disposed when the web request ends.

This would address your concerns re: race conditions about accessing user during requests

For SignalR however it looks like a slight change would be needed as it's requests are not following the same flow

```
public class ChatHub : Hub {
    private IUserContext user;

    public override Task OnConnected() {
        user = GetAuthInfo();
        return Clients.All.joined(user);;
    }

    protected IUserContext GetAuthInfo() {
        var user = Context.User;
        return new UserContext(user);
    }

    public void Send(string name, string message){
        var userId = user.UserId;
        //...        
    }
}
```

That leads me to think that a factory could be created to abstract out the tight coupling to implementation concerns.

```
public interface IUserContextFactory {
    IUserContext Create(IPrincipal user);
}

public class UserContextFactory {
    public IUserContext Create(IPrincipal user) {
         return new UserContext(user);
    }
}
```

And configured in startup with its own container to avoid conflict with web request scopes

```
public void ConfigureSignalR(IAppBuilder app) {
    // Create the container as usual.
    var container = new Container();
    // Register your types, for instance:
    container.Register<IUserContextFactory,UserContextFactory>();    
    //Set SignalR DI
    var config = new HubConfiguration() {
        Resolver = new SignalRSimpleInjectorDependencyResolver(container);
    };
    app.MapSignalR(config);
}
```

Which would then finally allow the following

```
public class ChatHub : Hub {
    private IUserContextFactory userFactory;

    public ChatHub(IUserContextFactory userFactory) {
        this.userFactory = userFactory;
    }

    public void Send(string name, string message){
        var user = userFactory.Create(Context.User);
        var userId = user.UserId;
        //...        
    }
}
```

References:

[Simple Injector Documentation : ASP.NET MVC Integration Guide](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mvcintegration.html#asp-net-mvc-integration-guide)

[Simple Injector Documentation : ASP.NET Web API Integration Guide](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webapiintegration.html#asp-net-web-api-integration-guide)

[Microsoft Documentation: Using IoC Containers in SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/advanced/dependency-injection#using-ioc-containers-in-signalr)

[Microsoft Documentation: Authentication and Authorization for SignalR Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/security/hub-authorization)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution and it works great with web forms and mvc. However, I noticed an issue with signalr. I added `IUserContext` parameter to a hub constructor and when running in debug mode Simple Injector throws exception `The IUserContext is registered as 'Web Request' lifestyle, but the instance is requested outside the context of a Web Request.`. After that, hub methods return `user.UserId` as last user who connected to hub, not the one who makes actual call to hub method. I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @sigurd ok thanks for the feedback, will review and update

Comment: @sigurd so far upon further research it looks like for SignalR you have to access the user principal directly when connected. Will include a link from documentation and see if I can find a work around

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your efforts. I ran into signalr not using middleware, too.

Comment: @sigurd the work around I am thinking of that would still allow DI is to create a factory that would build the user context based on the passed in user principal.

Comment: Yes, I initially thought that I can use `Thread.CurrentPrincipal`, but I was worried if it would work reliably in all edge cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152939/discussion-between-sigurd-and-nkosi).